# Git acting up - unadded files that are added

Tags: git

So doing the following, on a branch called "beta":

```
$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checko
ut:
        Documentation/packages/CoreTheme_Template_helpers.html
        Documentation/packages/default.html
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Ok,

```
$ git status
# On branch beta
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the untracked files in your worktree match a `.gitignore` pattern so `git status` ignores them.

On branch `master`, though, those two files, which exist untracked and ignored in your current worktree, are tracked.  (Git will not ignore tracked files). So checking out `master` would stomp on uncommitted content in your worktree, and git won't do that either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems on your branch `beta`, you have those `Documentation/packages/*` files added in your `.gitignore` list; those files exist but are not a part of the repo on this branch.

This could be happening in the `.gitignore` file in your repo root, or a `.gitignore` file in your `Documentation/` or `` `Documentation/packages/ `` directory, or locally ignored via `.git/info/exclude` file.

However, the same files are committed in the master branch (with same/ different content).

Thus, when you do a git checkout master, git throws up an error because it is trying to overwrite existing files.

Move/rename these files and do a checkout, and commit the ones you need later on to resolve the issue.

Comment: I checked the .gitignore, these are not added to the ignore list on any branch ... master, beta or development.

Comment: @LogicLooking Can you check `.git/info/exclude` as well? For any `Documentation/*` directory/file to be on ignore list?

Comment: @LogicLooking Also confirm whether the `Documentation/Packages/*` files exist otherwise on your branch `beta`

Comment: @LogicLooking Also, note that you might be having a `.gitignore` file within your `Documentation/` or `Documentation/Packages/` directories, so check them as well

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have files on your filesystem (untracked in the current branch) which exists in the branch that you're checkouting to.

Remove or delete them.

Comment: I'm sorry what? that doesn't make sense? I have untracked files in master? yet it wont let me switch to master? if I delete them then beta spazzes out being like "you deleted these two files ... " and these particular files have been pushed to github already so I'm not sure how their "untracked"

Comment: No he is saying untracked in beta, hence why git throws up the error, otherwise he would be overwriting files he doesn't know about. Can't say why they would be untracked in beta though.