# How to catch git error on checkout without checkout?

Tags: git

I want checkout to branch and for example i got error:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout

But `git-status` said me all is ok:

> On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean)

So i have to make a decision, if error exist i should run `git clean` if no - run with force `git checkout <branch> -f` but error only appear after `git checkout`, so it is or checkout or error.

Also unfortunately i cant use `git-ls-files -d` bc it just show deleted files comparing the current active branch and remote. I need same command which will show for current branch and one another branch.

And `git-ls-tree -r $branchName` show all changed files, i need filter for removed only us `-d`.

New idea is a after force checkout check via `git-ls-files` which files is diff with remote, but that files show like a cached with many others files...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git acting up - unadded files that are added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188448/git-acting-up-unadded-files-that-are-added)

Answer (score 1):

Read about the

```
--dry-run
```

parameter, which can be used with some git commands.